# asp.net resource customization

Tags: asp.net

Our web site( ASP.NET 4.0 ) makes heavy use of `meta:ResourceKey` in each control throughout for pretty much anything  you can see on a page and is customized from client to client. But the problem is that resource sometimes needs to be customized from client to client. For example if there is this string in a resource file `Label1ResourceText.Text = 'Welcome to Customer1 site'` then it needs to be changed to `Label1ResourceText.Text = 'Welcome to Customer2 site'` both in English and localized resource versions of the app when we install Customer2 version. I am wondering if it can be done with minimal customization work between each customer either programmatically or declaratively but without having to manually edit or produce different resource files for each customer.
Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use a single file or multiple files, your website will still have to determine which file to use or which key to use if you go with a single file approach.

Other than that, you will have to use two separate files.

An alternative would be to add a single resource file, say UIStrings.resx, to the resources folder. You could then store the following string in the resource file

WeclomeMessage = "Welcome to {0} site"

Then you can render the string using

```
Label1.Text = String.Format(Resources.UIStrings.WelcomeMessage, CustomerName);
```

in the code behind.

As an alternative to the code behind approach is to use

```
<asp:Label Text="<%= String.Format(Resources.UIStrings.WelcomeMessage, CustomerName)%>" />
```

[This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38907/ASP-NET-Localization-Quick-Reference#string) has some good information on how to utilize resource files.

Comment: Thanks, I like your alternative approach much better, as `CustomerName` is something that can be set in a config file or something like that per client.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227982%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can use different resx files and call them based on your business logic programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can it be done using single resource file?